# Make Panel's BackgroundImage "fadeout" on c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Panel. This panel has an opaque Background Image. I want to make it fade smoothly to 0 opacity. Since it hasn't a opacity property, what is the best way to make this effect?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.DrawImage with opacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519956/drawimage-with-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to use WPF to do this instead?  It would be much easier.  This is a bit of a trick in Winforms.  If what you really need to fade is the image, and not the panel, you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/960804/67038

**Edit**

Here's another example of fading an image:
[Fading out an image with transparency in WinForms UI (.NET3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960738/fading-out-an-image-with-transparency-in-winforms-ui-net3-5?lq=1)

Comment: Agreed. I will never understand why would anyone in 2013 do any winforms stuff.

Comment: @HighCore You will be more surprised if knowing that there are still people who are still using `Visual Basic 6.0`, that's true. and that's more surprising than `Windows Forms`. Any way I think `Windows Forms` is interesting. I love it forever. At least, `Windows Forms` can compare with `Java` and `WPF` is something better than `Java` in field of how easily you can customize your design.

Comment: It's for the C# class in my College, @HighCore

Comment: @FelipeFrancisco Are you trying to make the panel fade in (which will be difficult), or is it that you need for the image to fade in, and the image happens to be on a panel?  If the latter, have a look at that link in my answer above.  I think that will get you started.  Real shame it has to be Winforms -- in WPF, you can animate the opacity of any control with just a few lines of XAML.

Comment: @KingKing `Windows Forms can compare with Java` - Exactly. java belongs to the past century. It has never evolved. winforms == java == dinosaur. WPF == WinRT == current technology.

Comment: @HighCore `current technology` but not `dominant and prevalent` :) although I know `WPF` was born a long time ago. People predict that `Winforms` may live and still be prevalent in a few years more. :)

Comment: @kingking so does java. You may also argue that java is `dominant` (whatever that means). That doesn't change the fact that it's immenselly inferior technically.

Comment: @kingking If you haven't discovered XAML and MVVM, I suggest you do so, I guarantee your opinion will change and you will despise crappy code-behind practices as much as I do.

Comment: @HighCore as far as I know the Java class library is great and many programmers are using it in their projects. `Java` is just a language which helps them work with that library and I know there is another language better than `Java` called `Scala`. I'm really excited to learn that new stuff.

Comment: @HighCore I'll surely do. I love `WPF` just because I've heard how great it is. I like new stuff. never stop at only `Winforms` or `C#`, learning new stuff is very interesting.