# Set transparent background image

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent

I need to set a background image which is transparent and hasn't an opacity of 100%.
It is meant as a "loading screen" when the program starts.
I want it to be transparent and I am using a new form which has border style none.

I am not searching for this solution:

```
public Form1()
{
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Turquoise;
    this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
}
```

because this is just unsatisfactory, because of the less than 100% opacity, that the picture has.
And I neither want to use opacity of the form to solve this, because I am already using it for a kind of "fade in" of the form.

Does anybody know how to do this? Maybe there is a much simpler way to do this, that I don't know?

Sorry for my bad English.
Greetings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fading out an image with transparency in WinForms UI (.NET3.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960738/fading-out-an-image-with-transparency-in-winforms-ui-net3-5)

Comment: Yes the Picture is png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208767/display-only-an-image-with-transparency-in-a-windows-form) and You can use [link in the solution suggested there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226696/232530). It uses 32-bit PNG image and GDI functions. I haven't downloaded the source code, but in order to implement handling of Win32 calls, You can use [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) pages, where You should be able to find information about appropriate functions, for example [GetDC](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/getdc.html), [SelectObject](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/SelectObject.html) or [BLENDFUNCTION](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/BLENDFUNCTION.html).

Comment: Yep! `UpdateLayeredWindow` does the trick, but you cannot have any controls in the form. In this example is not a problem as it is just a loading screen.

Comment: Thx for solution. it's pretty difficult but i will try to do it like that

Comment: If You need more information, please let me know and I'll try to update the answer with more details.